# ReRendering of Component keeps propagates checkbox checked event React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a material ui checkbox formgroup that I m rendering dynamically based on the data received from the API. basically user receives a question with a set of answers. He checks all the answers that are valid and clicks next. If the server sends another question then the new question Is loaded and so on. The problem is that on the first attempt if user checks only the first checkbox for e.g and clicks next then the next loaded answers already has the first checkbox checked! same for any order. Any ideas regarding that? here is the code:

```
  <FormControl component="fieldset" className={classes.formControl}>
                        <button onClick={()=>{console.log(answers)}}>PUSSY</button>
                        <FormLabel component="legend">{state.question.text}</FormLabel>
                        <FormGroup>
                            {state.question.items.map((question,index)=>{
                                return(
                                    <FormControlLabel
                                        key={index}
                                        control={<Checkbox disableRipple={true} defaultChecked={false}  onChange={handleChangeMultiple} name={question.id}/>}
                                        label={question.name}
                                    />
                                )
                            })
                            }
                        </FormGroup>
                    </FormControl>
```

Heres the onchange handler:

```
 const handleChangeMultiple = (e)=>{
        if(e.target.checked) {
            setAnswers([...answers, e.target.name]);
        }
    }
```

And finally the Next button handler:

```
   const yesGroupMultipleNext = async e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        answers.map(answer=>{
            let obj = {};
            obj.id = answer;
            obj.choice_id = 'present';
            evidence.push(obj);
        });
        setAnswers([]);
        await makeDiagnosis(evidence)
            .then(res=>{
                console.log(res)
                dispatch({type:'SET_RESPONSE',payload:res.data});
                if(res.data.question.type === 'group_single' || res.data.question.type === 'group_multiple' || res.data.question.type === 'single' ){
                    console.log('new instance')
                    props.nextStep('questions');
                }
            })
            .catch(err=>console.log(err));
    };
```

The props.nextStep('question'); line basically calls an outer function to see which view to render. since it got 'questions' it will render this exact same view. Hope you can help me out here.

Comment: Try using onBlur instead of onChange.

Comment: Avoid using `key={index}`. If your `question` object has `id` use that as `key` instead.

Comment: @SILENT onBlur isn't supported on material UI checkbox. i went through their docs and can only see the onChange method.

Comment: @bertdida OMG That actually worked!!! shit i was going mad for 8 hours coz of this thank you. can you please answer below so I can accept it ?

Comment: In addition to what @bertdida said - React uses key to determine wether it should re-render a component. In your case - by using index as key and checking if the key has changed (it didn't), React decides not to re-render the checkbox.

Comment: @nirshabi Is that written somewhere on the docs? I once experienced this problem; and since then I never use `index` as `key`.

Comment: That is my understanding from the following lines (from the docs): "Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed. Keys should be given to the elements inside the array to give the elements a stable identity.", but maybe I have read it https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318 or https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#recursing-on-children

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React doesn't recommend using `index` as `key` when you `map` into components. Your `questions` seems to have `ids` on it, use that instead.

> We don’t recommend using indexes for keys if the order of items may change. This can negatively impact performance and **may cause issues with component state**.

[Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys)